# Correctly importing LZString in webpack project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying import [LZString](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/guide.html) 1.4.4 to my webpack project, however I'm getting this error in chrome console:

```
core.es5.js?de3d:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'compress' of undefined
at FileReader.reader.onload (file-upload.ts?e535:117)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?6524:392)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js?de3d:3890)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?6524:391)
at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js?6524:155)
at FileReader.eval (zone.js?6524:133)
```

I'm importing LZString this way:

```
import { LZString } from 'lz-string';
```

and the piece of code that is using LZString is this:

```
private compressAndChangeModel(file:File){
    let reader:FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        let compressed:string=LZString.compress(reader.result);
        this.modelChange.next(compressed);
    };
    reader.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log('Error when trying to generate base64: ', error);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

How is the correct way of import LZString in my webpack project?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`LZString` doesn't export a property called `LZString`](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/blob/master/typings/lz-string.d.ts). You could use a synthetic default import, `import LZString from 'lz-string';`.

However, `compress` is exported, so you can just use `import { compress } from 'lz-string'` and just use `compress()`.

If you don't like the generic `compress` name you can also alias it using `import { compress as lzStringCompress } from 'lz-string';` instead.

Comment: For decompression, use `import { decompress as lzStringDecompress } from 'lz-string';`